# UrlDownloadToFile doesn't work in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, download

I'm trying to download a file from the internet with Delphi XE2, but Nothing happens.
Here's my code:

```
uses URLMon;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Const
  SourceFile = 'http://www.google.com/intl/de/images/home_title.gif';
  DestFile = 'c:\download\home_title.gif';
begin
  UrlDownloadToFile(nil, PChar(SourceFile), PChar(DestFile), 0, nil);
end;
```

So my problem is: When I click the button, the program doesn't download the file.
I tried to download to another directory, I tried to download other files but nothing.
I can't get it to work.

What Am I doing wrong?

Please Help Me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. Most likely the problem is a local one. Perhaps a problem with your network connection. Or perhaps the directory `'c:\download'` does not exist.

To investigate your local problem, you'll need to make a note of the value returned by the function `UrlDownloadToFile`. It's an `HRESULT` and `S_OK` indicates success. Other values indicate failure. Once you know what the error code is, you should be able to track down your problem.

Having said that, `UrlDownloadToFile` doesn't seem to do a good job of returning meaningful error codes. For example, if you make `DestFile` be a path with non-existant folders, then the function still returns `S_OK`.

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123.aspx) does state: "URLDownloadToFile returns S_OK even if the file cannot be created and the download is canceled. If the szFileName parameter contains a file path, ensure that the destination directory exists before calling URLDownloadToFile. For best control over the download and its progress, an IBindStatusCallback interface is recommended."